# Mysql Stored Procedure if syntax

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I create a Stored procedure, that should take value from column 'alt1','alt2','alt3''alt4', and create a new row with each of that values.
This new value must have an incremental id.
However if condition is never met, although I know for sure there are many alt1, alt2, alt3, alt4 that aren't null.

EDIT:
On Database there are a lot of alt* NOT NULL, but in the stored variables Alt* are ALL NULL.

Thank you in advance

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS smonta_alias $$
CREATE PROCEDURE smonta_alias ( )
BEGIN
 DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE; 
 DECLARE tname VARCHAR(255);
 DECLARE nuovo_id INT DEFAULT 5000;
 DECLARE alt1 VARCHAR(255);
 DECLARE alt2 VARCHAR(255);
 DECLARE alt3 VARCHAR(255);
 DECLARE alt4 VARCHAR(255);
 DECLARE id INT;
 DECLARE idq INT;

 DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT `alt1` AS alt1, `alt2` AS alt2, `alt3` AS alt3, `alt4` AS alt4, `id` AS id, `id_quota` AS idq FROM `squadra` s WHERE
                                         `s`.alt1 IS NOT NULL OR 
                                         `s`.alt2 IS NOT NULL OR
                                         `s`.alt3 IS NOT NULL OR
                                         `s`.alt4 IS NOT NULL; 
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE; 

 OPEN cur1;
 tables_loop: LOOP
   FETCH cur1 INTO alt1, alt2, alt3, alt4, id, idq;
   IF done THEN
     LEAVE tables_loop;
   END IF;
   IF @alt1 IS NOT NULL THEN   
    SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `squadra` (id, id_quota, nome_squadra) VALUES (?,?,?)');  
    SELECT @s;
    PREPARE stmtd FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmtd USING @nuovo_id, @idq, @alt1;
    SET @nuovo_id = @nuovo_id + 1;
   END IF;

   IF @alt2 IS NOT NULL THEN   
    SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `squadra` (id, id_quota, nome_squadra) VALUES (?,?,?)');  
    SELECT @s;
    PREPARE stmtd FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmtd USING @nuovo_id, @idq, @alt2;
    SET @nuovo_id = @nuovo_id + 1; 
   END IF;

   IF @alt3 IS NOT NULL THEN   
    SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `squadra` (id, id_quota, nome_squadra) VALUES (?,?,?)');  
    SELECT @s;
    PREPARE stmtd FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmtd USING @nuovo_id, @idq, @alt3;
    SET @nuovo_id = @nuovo_id + 1; 
   END IF;

   IF @alt4 IS NOT NULL THEN   
    SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `squadra` (id, id_quota, nome_squadra) VALUES (?,?,?)');  
    SELECT @s;
    PREPARE stmtd FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmtd USING @nuovo_id, @idq, @alt4;
    SET @nuovo_id = @nuovo_id + 1;
   END IF;

 END LOOP;
END $$

DELIMITER ;

CALL smonta_alias;
```

Comment: Do you really need to use [13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)? I think you get what you need without using them.

Comment: When using cursors, you would need to compare [13.6.4.1. Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html) `alt*` and then assign them to [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) `@alt*` before executing [13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). `alt*` and `@alt*` are different variables.

Answer (score 0):

In IF statements use `alt1, alt2, alt2, alt4`. Not `@alt1, @alt2, @alt3, @alt4`.
When you declare variables don't use @.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but If conditions still hold false even removing the @ character...